# How to fix a not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object issue - Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

The idea of this functionality is when a user enters a location we add a marker in that location and pans too said marker and zooms into the location of the marker. All this is working relatively fine, however. It's giving me this error " Uncaught Kc {message: "not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object", name: "InvalidValueError". "

```
if(map.getZoom() == 2) {

    map.setCenter({lat:data.address_lat2, lng:data.address_lng2});
    map.panTo(marker.position);
    smoothZoom(map, 11, map.getZoom());

    var location = new google.maps.LatLng({lat:data.address_lat2, lng:data.address_lng2});
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    bounds.extend(location.position);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

This is my smoothZoom function

```
function smoothZoom (map, max, cnt) {
   if (cnt >= max) {
        return;
    } else {
        z = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function(event){
        google.maps.event.removeListener(z);
        smoothZoom(map, max, cnt + 1);
    });
        setTimeout(function(){map.setZoom(cnt)}, 150);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: It's a fairly big code base and there are some aspects that rely on other aspects. Especially entering a postcode or location so providing a minimal example will take a fair amount of time. I shall get on with it when I continue working hours of my day.

Answer (score 1):

A [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng) doesn't have a constructor that takes a [google.maps.LatLngLiteral](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngLiteral) as the argument. This is not valid syntax:

```
var location = new google.maps.LatLng({lat:data.address_lat2, lng:data.address_lng2});
```

Should be:

```
var location_place = new google.maps.LatLng(data.address_lat2, data.address_lng2);
```

or:

```
var location_place = {lat:parseFloat(data.address_lat2), lng:parseFloat(data.address_lng2)};
```

(you only need the `parseFloat` if they are strings)

**Also:** `location` is not a good variable name. (see [ref1](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm) or [ref2](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp))

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have tried what you suggested with no luck with the error still returning. Generally confused.

Comment: This can't be. Is the error coming from another line in your code? Make sure you apply the above to all your code. If you still have issues, update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that allows to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have personally commented code bit by bit and narrowed it down to a few lines of code  and that's this 

var location = {lat:parseFloat(data.address_lat2), lng:parseFloat(data.address_lng2)};
 bounds2.extend(location.position);

Comment: `location` is not a good variable name. (see [ref1](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm) or [ref2](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp))

Comment: Luckily this wasn't the issue but I get why it's not a good variable name. Thank you for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that this line of code bounds.extend(location.position); should've been bounds.extend({lat:data.address_lat2,lng:data.address_lng2});